# Did any students obtain the power to become an animagus during the Harry potter story line?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

In the books we learn that James, Sirius, Pettigrew all became animagi while at school. Professor McGonnagell was obviously an animagus from well before Harry Potter was even born.

**Did any students at Hogwarts become animagi *during* the events of the Harry Potter novels?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nope.** Of the [named animagi](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Animagus), **all of them** were capable of transforming before Harry Potter was born and of the remaining ([unnamed Animagi](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_five_Animagi)), none appear to have registered during Harry's school years.

We've since learned (via [pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/uagadou)) that a team of 14 year olds from the Uagadou School of Magic have

> *"recently"*

demonstrated their ability to turn into animals such as elephants and cheetahs but obviously these aren't *Hogwarts* students and hence don't count toward your question.

Comment: Urgh. Does JKR think that everyone in Africa lives in the Serengeti?